# Создать базовый образ в Docker для Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Есть необходимость создать базовый docker образ программы написанной для Windows. ОС в образ нет необходимости загружать, т.к. программа всегда будет открываться в Windows.
В интернете про создание своего базового образа для windows ничего не нашел, только с готовыми образами windows-nano, windows-core и т.д.

Может скажите, где можно это поискать!?
Может быть кто сам собирал?

Comment: Уточните, зачем докер для win-программы, запускаемой в win? Покажите пример какой-то. Ничего не понятно

Comment: Нужно взять https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-nanoserver за основу и добавить в образ программу? Тогда в мане все описано: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/building-sample-app

Comment: @TotalPusher, потому что нужно запустить несколько несвязанных между собой экземпляров приложений написанных для windows со своими БД

Comment: @TotalPusher, без ос вообще никак? Приложение написано на .net framework.
Вчера нашел образы .net для Docker, в частности Runtime. Может быть можно что-то с ними поколдовать?

Comment: См выше мой коммент. Есть мана как контейнеризировать .NET, там написано. Если что-то не понятно, уточняйте более конкретно.